# How can i test Android HCE on my Laptop using ADT?

Tags: android, adt, nfc, eclipse-adt, hce

is there a way to simulate an NFC transaction using  HCE (Host Card Emulation) on Android 4.4 within my ADT IDE using an emulator?...are there such emulators available that support HCE?
Basically what i am trying to do is to develop an app without having to actually purchase an Android 4.4 device ? what are the options available?..any thoughts/ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The NFC Forum has a plugfest the week of March 24th in SFO, you could ask them if this is a use case they will have set up.

Answer (score 1):

NFC is hardware specific so I believe that using just an emulator is not possible. Moreover, not all Android 4.4 devices support HCE.

In addition, if you want to simulate a transaction you will need to have a POS that sends APDU commands to your HCE service.